# Upload multiple images before submit them

Tags: php, image, forms

I have a website where I can upload multiple images, the problem is when I try to upload more than 20 images. PHP has this option limited to 20 files and I want to know if it's possible to upload the images before submit them and then start uploading the images one for one.

EDIT: I checked the bluimp plugin and I would like do something similar but with basic code. The problem is that I don't know the start point

EDIT2: I found the solution, now I shold investigate about FormData

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using some jQuery. Ajax isn't that hard to code.

But there are also nice multi-file-uploaders out there like [blueimp](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), which already provide kind of a PHP-backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily upload more than one file at a time, here is a working example i am sharing with you....

```
<td valign="top">
      <input type="file"  id="paglink" maxlength="80" style="width:230px" name="files[]" multiple>

 </td>
```

and in database page,...

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
  $errors= array();
  foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
      if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
      }     
      //$query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
      $desired_dir="images/gallery";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
       if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not     exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //     rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
    // mysql_query($query);         
    }//else{
       //   print_r($errors);
    //}
}
//if(empty($error)){
    //echo "Success";
//}
}
?>
<?php
$b=$_FILES['files']['name'];

$cc=implode (",",$b);
$bb=explode (",",$cc); 



$f=$_POST['date'];
$et=$_POST['event_title'];
$ed=$_POST['event_date'];
$ed1=$_POST['event_date1'];


$j=$_POST['status'];

    $showon=$_POST['showon'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($bb); $i++) {

 $pp= $bb[$i];



$insert="insert into gallery set      image='$pp',date='$f',event_title='$et',event_date='$ed',event_date1='$ed1',status='$j',sho    wonpage='$showon'";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
}
```

Just apply this coding as such and you can upload as many images as you want at one time ,..
keep coding :)

Comment: With this code is possible to upload 50 images if the PHP file limit is 20?

Comment: I can change it if I'm working in my localhost when is in the server I can't modify it :/

Comment: you can do this in two cases, first if you have your own dedicated server, which is very costlier, and the second is just upload your own php.ini file on the server and save it in file manager.

Comment: What about if I can't do anything of both solutions? :/

Answer (score 0):

I heard that it's possible do it with FormData. I've never used it but if you can investigate you will know

Comment: I knew it. I made another question a few days ago asking how to do it with FormData and I found the solution. Thanks